# Errors reading a config file with ConfigParser in python 3,4

Tags: python, python-3.4

I am having a nagging error in Python 3.4 reading a config set file using the configparser . The Code was originally written for Python 2.7 but i no longer use it and i only use python 3.4 . I don't want any backward compatibility to python 2.7 at all. Only and only python 3.4

```
Error reading set file ./sets/diagnostic1.set
```

Above is the Error i am getting , when i run this code

```
from configparser import *
import re, os, ctypes, csv, calendar, datetime
from time import *
from ctypes import *

# Reads the config set file 
def readSetFile(file):
   try:
      #config = RawConfigParser()
      #config.readfp(FakeSecHead(open(file)))  #  readfp is deprecated from configparser 
      config = ConfigParser(delimiters=('=', ':'), comment_prefixes=('#', ';'), inline_comment_prefixes=';',  interpolation=None)
      config.read_file(FakeSecHead(open(file)))
      return config
  except:
    return False


# Reads fake or modified Section head in the config file
class FakeSecHead(object):
  def __init__(self, fp):
      self.fp = fp
      self.sechead = '[main]\n'

  def readline(self):
      if self.sechead:
        try:
            return self.sechead
        finally:
            self.sechead = None
      else:
        line = self.fp.readline()
      return re.sub('^SECTION_3.*$', '[additional]', line)
```

The  " diagnostic1.set "  file which contains the configs

```
  COMMENTS=Click view comments.
  SECTION_1=################# General Settings #################
  FRAMEWORK_CONFIG=./experts/config/TesingConfig.xml
  USE_ORDER_WRAPPER=0
  UI_FONT_SIZE=12
  UI_ERROR_INFO_COLOR=0
  UI_CUSTOM_INFO_COLOR=0
  SECTION_2=############## Common Strategy Settings ##############
  OPERATIONAL_MODE=1
  STRATEGY_INSTANCE_ID=25
  MAX_DRAWDOWN_PERCENT=100.00000000
  MAX_SPREAD_PIPS=100.00000000
  ENABLE_WFO=0
  WFO_WINDOW_SIZE=0
  PARAMETER_SET_POOL=0.00000000
  DISABLE_COMPOUNDING=0
  USE_INSTANCE_BALANCE=0
  INIT_INSTANCE_BALANCE=0.00000000
  TIMED_EXIT_BARS=31
  ATR_AVERAGING_PERIOD=3
  MAX_OPEN_ORDERS=1
  SECTION_3=############## Additional Strategy Settings ##############
  OPEN_ATR_MULTIPLIER=0.41000000
  OPEN_ATR_MULTIPLIER,F=1
  OPEN_ATR_MULTIPLIER,1=0.20
  OPEN_ATR_MULTIPLIER,2=0.01
  OPEN_ATR_MULTIPLIER,3=0.60
  TRADE_CONFIDENCE=2
```

So when i tested Running the code in python 3.4 console i get "False" which indicates it can't read the config set file.

```
 Python 3.4.3 |Anaconda 2.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Jun  4 2015, 15:29:08) 
 [GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
 >>> from configparser import *
 >>> import re, os, ctypes, csv, calendar, datetime
 >>> from time import *
 >>> from ctypes import *
 >>>
 >>> def readSetFile(file):
 ...     try:
 ...         #config = RawConfigParser()
 ...         #config.readfp(FakeSecHead(open(file)))  #  readfp will be deprecated from configparser edited by developer
 ...         config = ConfigParser(delimiters=('=', ':'), comment_prefixes=('#', ';'), inline_comment_prefixes=';',  interpolation=None)
 ...         config.read_file(FakeSecHead(open(file)))
 ...         return config
 ...     except:
 ...         return False

 >>> 
 >>> class FakeSecHead(object):
 ...     def __init__(self, fp):
 ...         self.fp = fp
 ...         self.sechead = '[main]\n'
 ...     def readline(self):
 ...         if self.sechead:
 ...             try:
 ...                 return self.sechead
 ...             finally:
 ...                 self.sechead = None
 ...         else:
 ...             line = self.fp.readline()
 ...         return re.sub('^SECTION_3.*$', '[additional]', line)
 ... 


 >>> readSetFile('./sets/diagnostics1.set')
 False
 >>>
```

Any help in being able to read the config set file the way it is. i have hundreds of config set files in the same format. but i can't seem to be able to read the files in Python 3.4

I have managed to modify code snippet from Patrick MAUPIN and it is able to read the config set file but now throws an key error in same part of the code

```
  numSystemsInPortfolio = len(setFilePaths)
  SettingsArrayType = numSystemsInPortfolio * ctypes.POINTER(c_double)
  settings = SettingsArrayType()
  for i in range(numSystemsInPortfolio):
     settings[i] = SettingsType()
     settings[i][IS_BACKTESTING] = True
     settings[i][DISABLE_COMPOUNDING] = float(sets[i].mainParams["DISABLE_COMPOUNDING"]['value']) if sets[
        i].content.has_option('main', 'DISABLE_COMPOUNDING') else 0
     settings[i][TIMED_EXIT_BARS] = float(sets[i].mainParams["TIMED_EXIT_BARS"]['value']) if sets[
        i].content.has_option('main', 'TIMED_EXIT_BARS') else 0
     settings[i][ORIGINAL_EQUITY] = config.getfloat("account", "balance")
     .....
     .....
     .....
     .....
     .....



    File "mycode.py", line 222, in main
i].content.has_option('main', "DISABLE_COMPOUNDING") else 0
    KeyError: 'DISABLE_COMPOUNDING'
```

Comment: You could try to debug how far it gets by adding `print(line)` after the `readline()`. Does that tell you where the problem is? Also, if you don't catch the error (using `try: except` in the `readSetFile`) then what error is thrown? Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: What is `SettingsType`?  The problem appears to be in there.  Or maybe `mainParams`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your config files are megabytes, it's easiest to read them in and then modify them rather than doing it a line at a time.  Also, StringIO is the best way to pass a file-like object to, well, anything.

Here is some code that works with that dataset for Python 3.4:

```
import re
from configparser import ConfigParser
from io import StringIO

# Reads the config set file
def readSetFile(fname):
    with open(fname, 'rb') as f:
        data = f.read().decode('UTF-8')

    cfg_splitter = re.compile('^SECTION_3.*$', re.MULTILINE).split

    cfg_parser = ConfigParser(delimiters=('=', ':'),
                            comment_prefixes=('#', ';'),
                            inline_comment_prefixes=';',
                            interpolation=None)

    data = cfg_splitter(data)
    data.insert(1, '[additional]')
    data.insert(0, '[main]')
    data = '\n'.join(data)
    print(data)
    cfg_parser.read_file(StringIO(data))
    return cfg_parser

config = readSetFile('sets/diagnostics1.set')
for sec in config.sections():
    print(sec, config.items(sec))

print(config.has_option('main', 'DISABLE_COMPOUNDING'))
print(config.has_option('main', 'DISABLE_COMPOUNDING2'))
```

When I execute it, I get:

```
main [('comments', 'Click view comments.'), ('section_1', '################# General Settings #################'), ('framework_config', './experts/config/TesingConfig.xml'), ('use_order_wrapper', '0'), ('ui_font_size', '12'), ('ui_error_info_color', '0'), ('ui_custom_info_color', '0'), ('section_2', '############## Common Strategy Settings ##############'), ('operational_mode', '1'), ('strategy_instance_id', '25'), ('max_drawdown_percent', '100.00000000'), ('max_spread_pips', '100.00000000'), ('enable_wfo', '0'), ('wfo_window_size', '0'), ('parameter_set_pool', '0.00000000'), ('disable_compounding', '0'), ('use_instance_balance', '0'), ('init_instance_balance', '0.00000000'), ('timed_exit_bars', '31'), ('atr_averaging_period', '3'), ('max_open_orders', '1')]
additional [('open_atr_multiplier', '0.41000000'), ('open_atr_multiplier,f', '1'), ('open_atr_multiplier,1', '0.20'), ('open_atr_multiplier,2', '0.01'), ('open_atr_multiplier,3', '0.60'), ('trade_confidence', '2')]
True
False
```

Comment: The configs are extremely small about  25 lines ( 1.7kB) each. Hey patrick i am able to get further than before. it is able to read the config set file but throws a Keys Error as indicated above

Comment: @JourneyMan --  I don't think you're showing enough code to diagnose that new problem -- I've modified the answer to show that has_option works on the config record...

Comment: I traced it to part of the code with wrong ( key,value )  mapping . Your answer solved file reading issue . Thanks